# Export Certain Columns of All Tables in Database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a little problem. I have two MySQL databases, and I want to move all of the tables from one into the other, except when I use the normal PHPMyAdmin export, it comes up with an error because of my ID column. How can I copy the whole database into the other one, except without copying that one table in PHPMyAdmin? Also, I can't just copy tables manually because I have alot of tables. I know that this may involve looping over all of the tables in a database. Anybody know of a way to do that (I am OK if it uses PHP)?
All of the tables are exactly the same in structure, and follow this structure:

```
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, # The one I don't want to copy (it is also a primary key)
col1 varchar(5), # Want to copy all of these.
col2 varchar(15),
col3 varchar(1000),
col4 varchar(20)
```

All I am wanting to do is copy all of the tables from one database to another database, except without copying the `id` column of each entry. So, for example, if I was just to add one entry manually I would use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable ...`, and then `INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES (value1, value2, value3, value4)`. Note that I am not inserting the `id` column.

Comment: It never ceases to amaze me how many questions here refer to some error without disclosing what the error is.  Does it not seem relevant?

Comment: The error is simply MySQL saying that it will stop doing the query because the entry to add has the same ID as one already in the table.

Comment: [Error 1062](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_dup_entry), then?  So the destination database already contains populated tables?  Do you want to retain those records, or replace them?  There's a lot of detail missing from your question.

Comment: As I said, I want to move tables from one into the other, implying that I do want to retain the records.

Comment: So then how do you envisage the data being merged?  What if there are foreign key references?  To which of the colliding records should they refer after the merge has completed?

Comment: Take a look at the new code.

Comment: Do you want to add the columns to the existing tables, or do the existing tables already have the columns and do you want to add the value of those columns to the table?

Comment: @Lex As I said, the structure of all of the tables in both databases is exactly the same. In other words, I just want to add a new entry to the table with the data from the table from the other database.

Comment: @mrfishie Add clear example (source and destination tables) - which lines to copy, which to skip, which to merge or replace (if needed).

Comment: I'm downvoting because the question needs to be way more specific about what behaviour the questioner wants to see, and what they've tried so far. See the 5 previous comments asking for clarification. Your bounty points will go further if you improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can crete PHP script to get all of your tables and do looping to insert into your new tables. If the structure is the same then it should be easier to copy all of them. Here the ideas:

Get all tables

```
$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM DB1";
$query = mysql_query($sql);    

// save the result as $old_tables

$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM DB2";
$query = mysql_query($sql);    

// save the result as $new_tables
```

Loop the result and insert to your other tables, create if it does not exist:

```
foreach($old_tables as $table){
    if(!in_array($table, $new_tables)){
        // create table with the name $table in DB2
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO DB2.$table(col1, col2, col3, col4) SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM  DB1.$table";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

The easiest way is using DB Admin Tool like SQLYog, Navicat, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
select concat( 'INSERT INTO destination_db.destintation_table 
(col1, col2, col3, col4)
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM ',a.table_name,';' )
from information_schema.tables a 
where a.table_name like 'table_prefix_%';
```

should give you code to run assuming your tables all have a prefix ? After its come back run the query it returns

Comment: None of the table names have a prefix. Also, is this going to loop through all of the tables?

Comment: You can also query the information_schema.tables table based on the database name, so a table prefix is not required. This query will output a string containing all the insert queries. However, note that they will all have the same columns, so this probably needs some tweaking.

Comment: his original query said they all have the same columns

Answer (score 0):

If you have a user that has access to both databases, you can do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO destination_db.destintation_table 
    (col1, col2, col3, col4)
    SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM source_db.source_table
```

Comment: I can't just copy tables manually because I have alot of tables. Also, would there be an easy way to do it with PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: Another option would be to execute an update query on the tables that you want to copy to add a certain number to the id column to make sure there aren't any collisions. This would also require a query on each table you want to copy though. I can't think of a better way...

Comment: Do you know of any way to loop through all of the tables in a database? Because if I could do that, then I could run the MySQL code for each table.

Comment: Maybe with a stored procedure, but I'm not sure. Or maybe you can create a PHP script and run that?

Comment: Is there any way to do it in PHPMyAdmin (like how you can do Export)? I would prefer that to writing a PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

This guy here has a bash script that can get table names from a database and perform an action on each one: http://wozia.com/blog/tips/bash-script-to-repair-all-mysql-tables-for-all-databases/

If you were to combine that with @Lex's answer above, it might do what you are looking for. Specifically, use the second file only on the linked page, and change the *mysql* line to something like:

```
INSERT INTO targetdb.$TABLENAME (col1, col2, col3 col4)
    VALUES (SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
            FROM sourcedb.$TABLENAME)
```

I'm sure you'd have to work it a little to have it reference the correct columns. You'd also be stuck with no duplicate or error checking, but I assume you've already considered that.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is the crazy approach.

1) Do a dump of your MySQL database

```
mysqldump -h localhost -u <user> -p<password> <database> > dump.sql
```

2) Open dump.sql with Vim and add (col1, col2, col3, col4) after the name of all tables

```
vim dump.sql
:%s/INSERT INTO `\(.*\)`/INSERT INTO `\1`(col1, col2, col3, col4)/g
```

3) Now remove the first value after VALUES, which should be the id for each row.

```
:%s/VALUES (\d\+,/VALUES (/g
```

4) Remove all tables you don't want to copy from the dump. Apply the dump to your destination database.

Answer (score 0):

I've used "Navicat for MySQL" to copy all sorts of data between databases. It sounds like it might work well for your use case. Navicat is quite flexible when it comes to cross-database data management. You can download a 30-day trial, experiment with it and decide if it works for you. http://www.navicat.com

Note: I do not work for Navicat...I'm just a satisfied customer.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution - PHP needs be configured in sudoers

```
<?php

// Dump and recover 

system("mysqldump -u root -ppassword -h localhost --ignore-table=my_db_name.my_table_name1 --ignore-table=my_db_name.my_table_name2 my_db_name | mysql -u root -ppassword -h remote_host my_db_name");
```

If you not needs as PHP you can run just this command line in the shell

```
mysqldump -u root -ppassword -h localhost --ignore-table=my_db_name.my_table_name1 --ignore-table=my_db_name.my_table_name2 my_db_name | mysql -u root -ppassword -h remote_host my_db_name
```